# How to use section in exam class

Tags: sectioning, exam

I am using latex exam class and need to sectioning questions like

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
  \begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
    \section{First Section}
    \question
    First question
    \question
    Second question
    \section{Second Section}
    \question
    First question
    \question
    Second question
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

This works, but doesn't align properly under section heading as well as not numbering like 1.1, 1.2 etc. Any option for that?

Probably a solution is updating question font and size to that of a section heading and use part/sub part. Any help to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!. Please provide complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example)  with `\documentclass{...}` on the beginning, used package and defined new commands, followed with `\begin{document}` showed code snipped and `\end{document}`on the end. Without MWE we can only guessing what is going on.

Comment: Updated with MWE.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution, although I'm not sure how this will affect the built in answers and grading.  Normally exam organizes by `\question`, `\part` and `\subpart`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.\arabic{question}}
\patchcmd{\questions}{10.}{\thequestion.}{}{}% fix left margin

\begin{document}
  \section{First Section}
  \begin{questions}
    \question
    \blindtext
    \question
    Second question
    \end{questions}
  \section{Second Section}
  \begin{questions}
    \question
    First question
    \question
    Second question
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

The patch will make each question margin precisely aligned, but different questions will have different margins.

---

This solution uses the `\fullwidth` macro inside the questions environment.  I assume you aren't planning on using a table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% opener for can of worms
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]% #1 = title
{\stepcounter{section}%
\setcounter{question}{0}%
\fullwidth{\smallskip\textbf{\large #1}}}

\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.\arabic{question}}
\patchcmd{\questions}{10.}{\thequestion.}{}{}% fix left margin

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
   \mysection{First Section}
    \question
    \blindtext
    \question
    \blindtext
   \mysection{Second Section}
    \question
    First question
    \question
    Second question
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: second demo]

Comment: This is fine, but still indent is not proper for the second line of questions, see

Comment: [link](https://s17.postimg.org/4y0wepp0v/indent.png) Image

Comment: My idea was make basic question font larger (size of section heading) without marks/points thus it can be used for heading, then use part/sub part for making actual questions. Is it possible? then there will not be problem for indent, but I am not sure about section numbers in this case.