# How to create a Title Answer using exam package?

Tags: exam, answers

I've been a user of this place for a long time and searched several solutions about typing latex correctly.

I've tried to write a simple exam paper and similar to this @Phil Hirschorn's answer like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246271/defining-new-command-for-multiple-choice-questions) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286628/mcqs-exam-package?rq=1). I have problems with making 2 columns using the mcq tests.

I really like making a simple exam to look like this:

[image]

and when I use `\showallanswers` we print this header

[image]

Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multicol}
```

% Accumulate the answers. Unmodified from Phil Hirschorn's answer
% [Showing Solutions of the Questions "separately"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15350/showing-solutions-of-the-questions-separately/15353)
\newbox\allanswers
\setbox\allanswers=\vbox{}

\newenvironment{answer}
{%
    \global\setbox\allanswers=\vbox\bgroup
    \unvbox\allanswers
}%
{%
    \bigbreak
    \egroup
}

\newcommand{\showallanswers}{\par\unvbox\allanswers}
% End Phil's answer

% Is there a better way?
\newcommand*{\getanswer}[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlj1T.png){%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{a}}
    {\begin{answer}\thequestion. (a)~#1\end{answer}}
    {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{b}}
        {\begin{answer}\thequestion. (b)~#2\end{answer}}
        {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{c}}
            {\begin{answer}\thequestion. (c)~#3\end{answer}}
            {\ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{d}}
                {\begin{answer}\thequestion. (d)~#4\end{answer}}
                {\begin{answer}\textbf{\thequestion. (#5)~Invalid answer choice.}\end{answer}}}}}
}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%usage \choice{ }{ }{ }{ }
%(A)(B)(C)(D)
\newcommand{\fourch}[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlj1T.png){
    \par
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{@{}p{0.23\textwidth}}}
        (a)~#1 & (b)~#2 & (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
    \end{tabular}
    \getanswer{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
}

%(A)(B)
%(C)(D)
\newcommand{\twoch}[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlj1T.png){
    \par
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
        (a)~#1 & (b)~#2
    \end{tabular}
    \par
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{@{}p{0.46\textwidth}}}
        (c)~#3 & (d)~#4
    \end{tabular}
    \getanswer{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
}

%(A)
%(B)
%(C)
%(D)
\newcommand{\onech}[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlj1T.png){
    \par
    (a)~#1 \par (b)~#2 \par (c)~#3 \par (d)~#4
    \getanswer{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
}

\newlength\widthcha
\newlength\widthchb
\newlength\widthchc
\newlength\widthchd
\newlength\widthch
\newlength\tabmaxwidth

\setlength\tabmaxwidth{0.96\textwidth}
\newlength\fourthtabwidth
\setlength\fourthtabwidth{0.25\textwidth}
\newlength\halftabwidth
\setlength\halftabwidth{0.5\textwidth}

\newcommand{\choice}[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlj1T.png){%
\settowidth\widthcha{AM.#1}\setlength{\widthch}{\widthcha}%
\settowidth\widthchb{BM.#2}%
\ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
    \settowidth\widthchb{CM.#3}%
\ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%
    \settowidth\widthchb{DM.#4}%
\ifdim\widthch<\widthchb\relax\setlength{\widthch}{\widthchb}\fi%

% These if statements were bypassing the \onech option.
% \ifdim\widthch<\fourthtabwidth
%     \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
% \else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
% \ifdim\widthch>\fourthtabwidth
%     \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
% \else
%      \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
%  \fi\fi\fi}

% Allows for the \onech option.
\ifdim\widthch>\halftabwidth
    \onech{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
\else\ifdim\widthch<\halftabwidth
\ifdim\widthch>\fourthtabwidth
    \twoch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
\else
    \fourch{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
\fi\fi\fi}

\begin{document}

\Large

\noindent{\bf Ma 12 Long Test 1\hfill 9 February 2017}

\medskip\hrule

`\begin{questions}

\question Um capacitor $C$ é submetido a uma tensão $V$. A energia armazenada no capacitor é igual a: 
\choice{$CV^2$}{$0.5CV^2$}{$2CV^2$}{$CV$}{b}

\question Uma tensão V é aplicada a um circuito RL em série. A corrente em regime permanente é igual a: 
\choice{$V/R$}{$V/L$}{$\dfrac{V}{\sqrt{R^2+L^2}}$}{zero}{a}

\question If the amplitude of a complex number is $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ then the number is
\choice{purely imaginary}{purely real}{0}{neither real nor imaginary}{a}

\question The value of $i + i^{22} + i^{23} + i^{24} + i^{25}$ is
\choice{i}{-i}{1}{-1}{c}

\question The volume generated by rotating the triangle with vertices at (0, 0), (3, 0) and (3, 3) about x-axis is
\choice{$18\pi$}{$2\pi$}{$36\pi$}{$9\pi$}{a}

\question To complete the song, the last answer should be
\choice{a}{b}{c}{d}{e} % Invalid answer choice


\question To complete the song, the last answer should be 
\choice{a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex a long tex}{b}{c}{d}{a} 
\end{questions}

%\newpage  %Uncomment to put on new age
\bigskip
Answer Key:
\bigskip  
\showallanswers % Phil Hirschorn
\end{document}`

[image]

Comment: It seems exam class supports both  [twocolumn], and \twocolumn[full width text].  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326940/how-to-use-section-in-exam-class

Comment: A little bit easier than the previous comment, have you tried to use \section*{Answer to Practice Exercises}, then adding a horizontal line with \hline or \rule, and the printing the question?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I know but when i use this option on class the choices seems overlap the column.

* I edit my main comment with the code.

Comment: Thank u @plr for this suggestion. I will try to make section without number when i resolve the first problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it seems that you want to do two things: create a two columns environment and then add the horizontal line in the answer section.

For creating two (or more columns), you can use the `multicol` package. A possible way of using it would be:

```
% more preamble
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}  % the number here is the number of columns
[  % the part between square brackets isn't divided into columns
\section{First Section}
All human things are subject to decay. And when fate summons, Monarchs must 
obey.
]  % now the columns start
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.
If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}

% rest of the document
```

Using the previous code with the `exam` package options, you can create several columns with your code.

For creating the horizontal rule without the number in the name of the section, you can use the following code:

```
\section*{Answer to Practice Exercises}
\hline
```

Or you can use `\rule` if you have problems with interline spacing:

```
\section*{Answer to Practice Exercises}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
```

This last part should be inside the `\showallanswers` (which, by the way, is a command from the `exam` package?)

Comment: have you ever test your solution with my code? I've tried to use multicols and doesnt fit well.

Comment: @miguel747, you either wrongly copied your code or something's wrong with it. I tried to compile it and got so many errors. Try to debug the code by commenting out certain parts and see if some of the errors change or disappear.
I see so many \newcommand defining new things that you might not fully understand. It's better to start from something more straightforward that you now and build from that.